# Error web scraping with rvest - Error in open.connection(x, "rb") : HTTP error 403

Tags: r, web-scraping

I'm having some trouble with the following code:

```
state <- read_html("https://www.state.gov/covid-19-recovery/vaccine-deliveries/")
```

As I receive the following error: `Error in open.connection(x, "rb") : HTTP error 403.`

This code has always worked for me before and works on another laptop but not my primary laptop so I know I messed something up. Any ideas would be much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: A 403 response means the server has determined the request is forbidden. Not all servers like to be scraped. If you call that end point too often, you may have been blocked. If the server is blocking your request, there's nothing you can really do. That's up to the server administrator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could bypass that with `polite`

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'rvest'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:readr':
#> 
#>     guess_encoding
library(polite)

page <- "https://www.state.gov/covid-19-recovery/vaccine-deliveries/" %>% 
  bow() %>% 
  scrape()

page %>% 
  html_elements(".tadv-color") %>% 
  html_text2() %>% 
  pluck(2) %>% 
  parse_number()
#> [1] 682437530
```

<sup>Created on 2023-01-07 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>